# It is possible to edit swipe to delete's (in UITableView) default text or translate it?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is possible to translate the swipe to delete message in a `UITableView` in iOS7?

I'm using two delegate methods to show de system swipe to delete button in specific rows of a `UITableView`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, implement the function of UITableViewDelegate:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> String! {
        return "your string" //or customize for each indexPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt* delegate present in `UITableViewDelegate` can be used to changed text of 'Delete' in tableview cell.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String? {
    return NSLocalizedString("erase".localized, comment: "")
}
```